# Is there a way to have NPM build a package after it is installed?

Tags: javascript, npm

I am currently using a [github url as a package](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#github-urls) which is basically a private base library for my application.

While a npm package will run the npm `build` script after it is installed it currently appears that if you use a github url as package [no build script will be run after installation](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3055) (Yes in that thread they say that if using npm 5 a `prepare` script will be run but from my testing it does not work).

I am wondering if it's possible to define a script in a *parent* npm package.json that would run the `build` script of a dependency after it installs?

Or if you have any better way to deal with this problem would be most welcome.